# Distance calculation/vector range significance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms, beginner

I'm trying to implement item based collaborative filtering. Do any distance calculations allow for weighting of certain ranges of values within each vector?

For example, I would like to be able to say values 10..22 within each vector are more significant than values within the range 0..10.

I've been experimenting with Pearson, Tanimoto and Euclidean algorithms, but they all seem to assume equal weighting for each value within the vector.

Am I approaching this problem in the right way, and if not, how do others deal with this problem?

Comment: Do you want to combine your features (vector dimensions) with nonlinear weights (like a squaring to give greater weight to larger values)? Or do you just want a linear combo? When you say "values 10..22", are 10 and 22 'values' of features or indexes to elements of your vector? Linear combinations are typically computed with just a vector (inner) product of your weights with the vectors your want to score. It turns out this product (a scalar) is proportional to the angle between your weight vector and each feature vector, so it's easy to explain/justify your weight choices.

Answer (score 1):

I created a scoring system ("Thomas Scoring System") to deal with this problem.  If you treat "distance" as a similarity score, this system should work for you. http://exploringpossibilityspace.blogspot.com/2014/02/thomas-scoring-system.html

> Here's Thomas Scoring System (TSS) in a nutshell: Treat each metric and their values as evidence that weigh for or against specific values in the performance index. This is an inference process and not an arithmetic calculation, as in the Usual Method. The output of TSS is an estimation of the Weight of Evidence for all index values.  The Weight of Evidence can be expressed as a probability distribution, where all the evidence weights sum to one.

To use your example, each range is a condition: A) 10 <= *x* <= 22; and B) *x* < 10. If A is true, then it weighs in favor of certain similarity (distance) scores.  If B is true, then it weights in favor of other similarity (distance) scores, but would have less weight compared to other evidence.

Answer (score 1):

You mention distance metrics but Pearson and Tanimoto are not. For Euclidean distance, simply scale the dimensions in question by some factor. For example doubling a dimension's values makes its contribution to distance larger and so makes the feature more important to the distance metric.

On a related note you may wish to look at the Mahalanobis distance which kind of accounts for covariance or 'redundancy' across dimensions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning the correct terminology. I'm trying to determine similarity, and believe the Tanimoto  and Pearson coefficients and Euclidean distance calculation can be used interchangeably to do this (source: Programming Collective Intelligence).

Comment: Similarity is large, but distance is small, when things are "alike". They're opposite in that sense, but, you could create some similarity metric out of distance, yes.

Comment: this answer doesn't address the question, which is how to "allow for *weighting of certain ranges of values* each vector."

Comment: It's trivial to convert a similarity to a distance. Just invert (`d=1/s`) or normalize (`0<s<1`) and subtract from 1 (`d=1-s`). That's why "distance" and "similarity" are used interchangably in books like PCI, because they are interchangeable ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is separable. You can 1) transform your vectors into a weighted combination of the "raw" vector dimensions and **then** 2) compute similarity or distance with things like correlation or Euclidean distance.

Problem 1: Weights are typically linear, just a matrix multiplied by your feature vector to rotate and scale it however you like. A matrix multiplication can even reduce your vectors dimensions (all the way down to a scalar score, if you like). The state of the art for dimension reduction and optimal feature vector transformation is SVD/PCA/LSI/LDA/NMF. FYI, the "eigenvectors" that some of these approaches produce are simply the columns or rows of your transformation matrix, the eigenvalues are the relative importance/weight of each of your new vectors. Some eigenvalues will be zero if you're doing dimension reduction and there's redundancy in your features.

Problem 2: Some common distance metrics based on [vector norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) are

- L_1 (Manhattan)
- L_2 (Euclidian)
- L_inf (Supremum)
- Cosine (vector product)
- Fractional (p-norm)

The state-of-the-art distance metric for high-dimensional problems is [fractional distance or p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) which is like Euclidean distance/norm, but the exponent is set to a value between 0 and 1 rather than 2.